# Java open BufferedImage in default OS image viewer

Tags: java, operating-system, default, bufferedimage

How do I open a BufferedImage in default OS's image viewer? I suspect that I would have to save it first somewhere, but I can't think of steps that would follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you save it to somewhere, you can use [java.awt.Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) to open it, which will use the default program for that file type. So your code would look like this:

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.open(new File("C:\\Path\\To\\Image.png"));
```

Comment: Also, if you don't want to store the file for later, but just want to be able to open it, using `File.createTempFile(...)` and write to that is probably a good idea.